# How Can I Use Order By In Aggregate Function

Tags: sql

I have a sql table seems like below

```
ID  AccountName Credit Debit CurrentBalance
1   John         10     0     10
2   Smith        20     0     20
3   Angel        0      10    20
4   John         30     0     40
5   Smith        0      10    10
6   Angel        30     0     50
```

Expected Result

```
AccountName TotalCredit TotalDebit CurrentBalance
John        40          0          40
Smith       20          10         10
Angel       30          10         50
```

I want the sum of credit and debit of every account and also the latest currentbalance of each account.

I have used this query

```
select AccountName, 
       SUM(CreditAmount) As CreditAmount, 
       SUM(DebitAmount) As DebitAmount, 
       MAX(CurrentBalance) As CurrentBalance 
from TransactionInfo 
GROUP BY AccountName;
```

Comment: Please tag appropriate database with your question.

Comment: What's your expected `order by`?

Comment: Are you running into an error when you add `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports `ROW_NUMBER`, then here is one way to do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM TransactionInfo
)

SELECT
    AccountNumber,
    SUM(Credit) AS TotalCredit,
    SUM(Debit) AS TotalDebit,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CurrentBalance END) AS CurrentBalance
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    AccountNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you Want to ordering the output record in aggregate function , just write the ORDER BY [columnindex from your query] e.g. in your query , if you want to ordering your output by AccountName then you can use ORDER BY 1 [AccountName], ORDER BY 2 [SUM(CreditAmount)], ORDER BY 3
SUM(DebitAmount)  etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

**NOTE:** Considering MAX(ID) for a user will be the latest.

```
SELECT AccountName, 
SUM(CreditAmount) As CreditAmount, 
SUM(DebitAmount) As DebitAmount, 
(   SELECT CurrentBalance 
    FROM TransactionInfo B 
    WHERE B.AccountName = A.AccountName
    AND B.ID = (SELECT MAX(C.ID) FROM TransactionInfo C WHERE C.AccountName = A.AccountName)
) AS CurrentBalance
FROM TransactionInfo A GROUP BY AccountName;
```